# Deserialize array of key value pairs using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Given the following json:

```
[ {"id":"123", ... "data":[{"key1":"val1"}, {"key2":"val2"}], ...}, ... ]
```

that is part of a bigger tree, how can I deserialize the "data" property into:

```
List<MyCustomClass> Data { get; set; }
```

or

```
List<KeyValuePair> Data { get; set; }
```

or

```
Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
```

using Json.NET? Either version will do (I prefer List of MyCustomClass though). I already have a class that contains other properties, like this:

```
public class SomeData
{
   [JsonProperty("_id")]
   public string Id { get; set; }
   ...
   public List<MyCustomClass> Data { get; set; }
}
```

where "MyCustomClass" would include just two properties (Key and Value). I noticed there is a KeyValuePairConverter class that sounds like it would do what I need, but I wasn't able to find an example on how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: i used this wizard as well http://json2csharp.com/ to generate class for deserialized

Answer (score 35):

The simplest way is deserialize array of key-value pairs to `IDictionary<string, string>`:

```
public class SomeData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> Data { get; set; }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = "{ \"id\": \"123\", \"data\": [ { \"key1\": \"val1\" }, { \"key2\" : \"val2\" } ] }";

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeData>(json);
}
```

But if you need deserialize that to your own class, it can be looks like that:

```
public class SomeData2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public List<SomeDataPair> Data { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDataPair
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = "{ \"id\": \"123\", \"data\": [ { \"key1\": \"val1\" }, { \"key2\" : \"val2\" } ] }";

    var rawObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var obj2 = new SomeData2
    {
        Id = (string)rawObj["id"],
        Data = new List<SomeDataPair>()
    };

    foreach (var item in rawObj["data"])
    {
        foreach (var prop in item)
        {
            var property = prop as JProperty;

            if (property != null)
            {
                obj2.Data.Add(new SomeDataPair() { Key = property.Name, Value = property.Value.ToString() });
            }

        }
    }
}
```

See that I khow that `Value` is `string` and i call `ToString()` method, there can be another complex class.

Comment: The list of dictionaries works; thanks for that. Since the change I'm trying to make is part of a bigger library I'm trying to avoid having to write custom object initialization. I'm looking into writing a custom converter for my class (SomeData2 in your example). If I can't get it to work then I'll use your List of Dictionary method. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer. I was having same kind of json with array with key value. I just used public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> Data { get; set; } for that field and worked like charm.. my whole json was parsed fine!..

Comment: Note that this will not conserve the order of the original JSON - since a Dictionary will be sorted by the Key

Comment: Granted, that it doesn't populate one Dictionary<string, string> but I think that would be more logical. Seems silly to need an enumerable (or array) of IDictionary when the idea of a dictionary to begin with is to be a keyed _collection_ of values.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Boo for your answer but in my case I needed to take some small adjustements.
This is how my JSON looks like:

```
{
    "rates": {
        "CAD": 1.5649,
        "CZK": 26.118,
        ...
    },
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2020-08-16"
}
```

And my DTO looks like the following:

```
public IDictionary<string, decimal> Rates { get; set; }
public string Base { get; set; }
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

So the only adjustement was to remove the `IEnumerable` around the `IDictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomClassConverter))]
public class MyCustomClass
{
  internal class MyCustomClassConverter : JsonConverter
  {
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

      foreach (var prop in jObject)
      {
        return new MyCustomClass { Key = prop.Key, Value = prop.Value.ToString() };
      }

      return null;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
      return typeof(MyCustomClass).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
  }

  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Datum
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public string key2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

i used this wizard as well [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com) to generate class for deserialized

for using that

```
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

IRestResponse restSharp= callRestGetMethodby_restSharp(api_server_url);
string jsonString= restSharp.Content;

RootObject rootObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
return Json(rootObj);
```

if you call rest by restsharp

```
    public IRestResponse callRestGetMethodby_restSharp(string API_URL)
    {
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient(API_URL);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        return response;
    }
```

also you can get this 6 line of restsharp from [getpostman.com](https://www.getpostman.com/) tools

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/ was a great suggestion! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, string>> Data as the most answers are recommending, but it is not the best idea, since it creates a new dictionary for each array key value item. I recommend to use List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> instead ( or you can create a custom class as well instead of using KeyValuePair )

```
var json = "[{ \"id\": \"123\", \"data\": [ { \"key1\": \"val1\" }, { \"key2\" : \"val2\" } ] }]";

List<SomeData> listSomeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SomeData>>(json);

public class SomeData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Data { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public SomeData(JArray data)
    {
        Data = data.Select(d => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        ((JObject)d).Properties().First().Name,
        ((JObject)d).Properties().First().Value.ToString()))
        .ToList();
    }
}
```