# How to deserialize specific Json node to Dictionary<string,object>?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have a JSON response which looks like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"more": false,
"results_html": "a lot of html in here",
"listinginfo": {
    "637640274112277168": {
        "listingid": "637640274112277168",
        "price": 50,
        "fee": 7,
        "publisher_fee_app": 730,
        "publisher_fee_percent": "0.10000000149011612",
        "currencyid": "2005",
        "steam_fee": 2,
        "publisher_fee": 5,
        "converted_price": 1,
        "converted_fee": 2,
        "converted_currencyid": "2003",
        "converted_steam_fee": 1,
        "converted_publisher_fee": 1,
        "converted_price_per_unit": 1,
        "converted_fee_per_unit": 2,
        "converted_steam_fee_per_unit": 1,
        "converted_publisher_fee_per_unit": 1,
        "asset": {
            "currency": 0,
            "appid": 730,
            "contextid": "2",
            "id": "6542776191",
            "amount": "1"
        }
    },
    "194035710805671301": {
        "listingid": "194035710805671301",
        "price": 0,
        "fee": 0,
        "publisher_fee_app": 730,
        "publisher_fee_percent": "0.10000000149011612",
        "currencyid": "2001",
        "asset": {
            "currency": 0,
            "appid": 730,
            "contextid": "2",
            "id": "6825071309",
            "amount": "0"
        }

    },

  }//end listinginfo
 //more fields here..
}
```

I Need to get the info just from the "listinginfo" node and add them to a *`dictionary<string, NewListedItem>`* where string would be for example: "637640274112277168", and the list will be of type "NewListedItem", containing all the info from that subnode. My classes look like that:

```
class listinginfo
{
    public Dictionary<string, NewListedItem> Items;

}
class Asset
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string appid { get; set; }
    public string contextid { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
}
class NewListedItem
{

    public string listingid { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string fee { get; set; }
    public string publisher_fee_app { get; set; }
    public string publisher_fee_percent { get; set; }
    public string steam_fee { get; set; }
    public string publisher_fee { get; set; }
    public string converted_price { get; set; }
    public string converted_fee { get; set; }
    public string converted_currencyid { get; set; }
    public string converted_steam_fee { get; set; }
    public string converted_publisher_fee { get; set; }
    public string converted_fee_per_unit { get; set; }
    public string converted_steam_fee_per_unit { get; set; }
    public string converted_publisher_fee_per_unit { get; set; }
    public Asset asset { get; set; }


}
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: If you're willing to use a third-party library JSon.Net could make this easier.  See this closely related question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789539/deserialize-array-of-key-value-pairs-using-json-net

Comment: @dazedandconfused seeing as the question is *tagged* [tag:json.net], I expect that is fine...

Comment: @MarcGravell - Oops, so it does.  No more commenting for me until the coffee starts doing its thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really very close.  Your classes will work fine as you've defined them, except you need to change the name of the dictionary property inside your root class from `Items` to `listinginfo` to mirror the JSON property name.  (Alternatively, you could use a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to map the `Items` dictionary to the `listinginfo` property in the JSON.)  After making that change, I would also recommend renaming your root class from `listinginfo` to something else that makes sense to you, like maybe `ListingResponse`, but that is not strictly necessary.

After those changes, your root class should look like this:

```
public class ListingResponse
{
    public Dictionary<string, NewListedItem> listinginfo { get; set; }
}
```

Or, if you prefer the attribute approach:

```
public class ListingResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("listinginfo")]
    public Dictionary<string, NewListedItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you should be able to deserialize your JSON into this class and your dictionary will be populated as you expect:

```
ListingResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListingResponse>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/V8LsXY

Comment: Ah, i solved it doing this: 
JToken root = JObject.Parse(response);
JToken testToken = root["listinginfo"];
and then pass the testToken to DeserializeObject.

anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So I wasn't able to do this in a clean way, but I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
 var jsonString = @"{
            'success': true,
            'more': false,
            'results_html': 'a lot of html in here',
            'listinginfo': {
                '637640274112277168': {
                    'listingid': '637640274112277168',
                    'price': 50,
                    'fee': 7,
                    'publisher_fee_app': 730,
                    'publisher_fee_percent': '0.10000000149011612',
                    'currencyid': '2005',
                    'steam_fee': 2,
                    'publisher_fee': 5,
                    'converted_price': 1,
                    'converted_fee': 2,
                    'converted_currencyid': '2003',
                    'converted_steam_fee': 1,
                    'converted_publisher_fee': 1,
                    'converted_price_per_unit': 1,
                    'converted_fee_per_unit': 2,
                    'converted_steam_fee_per_unit': 1,
                    'converted_publisher_fee_per_unit': 1,
                    'asset': {
                                        'currency': 0,
                        'appid': 730,
                        'contextid': '2',
                        'id': '6542776191',
                        'amount': '1'
                    }
                },
                '194035710805671301': {
                    'listingid': '194035710805671301',
                    'price': 0,
                    'fee': 0,
                    'publisher_fee_app': 730,
                    'publisher_fee_percent': '0.10000000149011612',
                    'currencyid': '2001',
                    'asset': {
                            'currency': 0,
                            'appid': 730,
                            'contextid': '2',
                            'id': '6825071309',
                            'amount': '0'
                        }

                },
                }
        }";
        var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

        List<JToken> results = json["listinginfo"].Children().Children().ToList();
        var dictionaryResults = new ListingInfo();

        foreach (var token in results)
        {
            var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewListedItem>(token.ToString());

            List<NewListedItem> listInfo = new List<NewListedItem>();
            listInfo.Add(info);

            dictionaryResults.Items = new Dictionary<string, List<NewListedItem>>();
            dictionaryResults.Items.Add(info.Listingid, listInfo);
        }
```

I also modified your class's property names a little bit :

```
 public class Asset
    {
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string Appid { get; set; }
        public string Contextid { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }
    public class NewListedItem
    {

        public string Listingid { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Fee { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("publisher_fee_app")]
        public string PublisherFeeApp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("publisher_fee_percent")]
        public string PublisherFeePercent { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("steam_fee")]
        public string SteamFee { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("publisher_fee")]
        public string PublisherFee { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("converted_price")]
        public string ConvertedPrice { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("converted_fee")]
        public string ConvertedFee { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("converted_currencyid")]
        public string ConvertedCurrencyid { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("converted_steam_fee")]
        public string ConvertedSteamFee { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("converted_publisher_fee")]
        public string ConvertedPublisherFee { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("converted_fee_per_unit")]
        public string ConvertedFeePerUnit { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("converted_steam_fee_per_unit")]
        public string ConvertedSteamFeePerUnit { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("converted_publisher_fee_per_unit")]
        public string ConvertedPublisherFeePerUnit { get; set; }
        public Asset Asset { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            public class TestClass
            {

                private void Test()
                {
                    var json = "{\r\n    \"637640274112277168\": {\r\n        \"listingid\": \"637640274112277168\",\r\n        \"price\": 50,\r\n        \"fee\": 7,\r\n        \"publisher_fee_app\": 730,\r\n        \"publisher_fee_percent\": \"0.10000000149011612\",\r\n        \"currencyid\": \"2005\",\r\n        \"steam_fee\": 2,\r\n        \"publisher_fee\": 5,\r\n        \"converted_price\": 1,\r\n        \"converted_fee\": 2,\r\n        \"converted_currencyid\": \"2003\",\r\n        \"converted_steam_fee\": 1,\r\n        \"converted_publisher_fee\": 1,\r\n        \"converted_price_per_unit\": 1,\r\n        \"converted_fee_per_unit\": 2,\r\n        \"converted_steam_fee_per_unit\": 1,\r\n        \"converted_publisher_fee_per_unit\": 1,\r\n        \"asset\": {\r\n            \"currency\": 0,\r\n            \"appid\": 730,\r\n            \"contextid\": \"2\",\r\n            \"id\": \"6542776191\",\r\n            \"amount\": \"1\"\r\n        }\r\n    },\r\n    \"194035710805671301\": {\r\n        \"listingid\": \"194035710805671301\",\r\n        \"price\": 0,\r\n        \"fee\": 0,\r\n        \"publisher_fee_app\": 730,\r\n        \"publisher_fee_percent\": \"0.10000000149011612\",\r\n        \"currencyid\": \"2001\",\r\n        \"asset\": {\r\n            \"currency\": 0,\r\n            \"appid\": 730,\r\n            \"contextid\": \"2\",\r\n            \"id\": \"6825071309\",\r\n            \"amount\": \"0\"\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n    }\r\n\r\n";
                    Dictionary<string, NewListedItem> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, NewListedItem>>(json);

                }
            }
            class listinginfo
            {
                public Dictionary<string, List<NewListedItem>> Items;

            }
            class Asset
            {
                public string currency { get; set; }
                public string appid { get; set; }
                public string contextid { get; set; }
                public string id { get; set; }
                public string amount { get; set; }
            }
            class NewListedItem
            {

                public string listingid { get; set; }
                public string price { get; set; }
                public string fee { get; set; }
                public string publisher_fee_app { get; set; }
                public string publisher_fee_percent { get; set; }
                public string steam_fee { get; set; }
                public string publisher_fee { get; set; }
                public string converted_price { get; set; }
                public string converted_fee { get; set; }
                public string converted_currencyid { get; set; }
                public string converted_steam_fee { get; set; }
                public string converted_publisher_fee { get; set; }
                public string converted_fee_per_unit { get; set; }
                public string converted_steam_fee_per_unit { get; set; }
                public string converted_publisher_fee_per_unit { get; set; }
                public Asset asset { get; set; }


            }
```

Comment: add references of Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.7

Comment: You dumped the rest of the JSON response and it works. But having the whole response and running your code, would give: Error converting value True to type 'steambot.NewListedItem'. Path 'success', line 1, position 15. , which from json we see, that it parses the first line too. The ideea, is how do i pass just the listinginfo node, to DeserializeObject ?