# C# Json.Net - How to deserialize an array of objects containing an array of other objects

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object

The Json data received from the http server is like this:

```
[
   {
      "token":"NlhYnzF0xqG"
   },
   [
      {
         "ts":"2019-03-21 14:06:22.123",
         "id":"CC_RTC_Second",
         "val":"22"
      },
      {
         "ts":"2019-03-21 14:06:00.096",
         "id":"CC_RTC_Minute",
         "val":"6"
      },
      {
         "ts":"2019-03-21 14:00:00.276",
         "id":"CC_RTC_Hour",
         "val":"14"
      }
   ]
]
```

I have tried some techniques presented in Newtonsoft.Json documentation, but I could not find the correct way. I spent two days by testing the solutions from StackOverflow answers, but with no success.

What C# types and techniques should I use in this particular case?

*Data structure can vary:

complete list of attributes is: td, id, val, flags, type, uts, nr.

All of them are strings.

Server can omit the attrs if they do not exist, so for example I can obtain only ts + id.

Is there any way how to work with such a data?*

Comment: Declare classes to hold your properties, then deserialize into those. Your question isn't clear, can you show us what you tried?

Comment: You will need a custom deserializer most likely, or you'll end up with objects/dynamic types, due to the fact that you have an array containing 1 object and then 1 array, so you can't create `List<T>`, here because you have different `T`'s for different elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize array of key value pairs using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789539/deserialize-array-of-key-value-pairs-using-json-net)

Comment: If working only with one object ts+id+val, I can use:

Comment: You can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json).Select(token => token is JArray ? (object)token.ToObject<List<Other>>() : (object)token.ToObject<TokenData>())`, replace with the right types.

Comment: If working only with one object ts+id+val, I can use: Dictionary<string, string> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json). Next I tried to use class and call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json). The class looked like this: public class MyClass {public string token {get; set;} public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,string>> data {get; set;}}. Now I realize, that this is no way :(

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dictionary<string,string>>>(your JSON Data Object gos here)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your json is quite complicated and its tedious job to create a class hierarchy for your json,

But one simple approach is that if you parse your JSON to `JArray` and then takes

- 0th element to one class
- And all remaining into list of another class

Then might be you can retrieve all your json data

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your json");

JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

Token token = jArray[0].ToObject<Token>();
jArray.RemoveAt(0);
RandomData[] tokenData = jArray.First.ToObject<RandomData[]>();

//--------------------Print Data to Console-------------------

Console.WriteLine(token.token + "\n");

foreach (var item in tokenData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ts: " + item.ts);
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + item.id);
    Console.WriteLine("val: " + item.val + "\n");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

And classes are,

```
class Token
{
    public string token { get; set; }
}

class RandomData
{
    public string ts { get; set; }
    public string td { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string val { get; set; }
    public string flags { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string uts { get; set; }
    public string nr { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** You need to install [NewtonSoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) NuGet package and import `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` namespace to your program.

Comment: Your answer completely solves my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is my version of answer:

```
var strData = @"[{
         'token': 'NlhYnzF0xqG'
       },
       [{
         'ts': '2019-03-21 14:06:22.123',
         'id': 'CC_RTC_Second',
         'val': '22'
       }, {
         'ts': '2019-03-21 14:06:00.096',
         'id': 'CC_RTC_Minute',

       }, {

         'id': 'CC_RTC_Hour',
         'val': '14'
       }]
     ]";   
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JToken>>(strData);
        var tokens = result.Where( x=> x.Type == JTokenType.Object).Select(x=> x.ToObject<Token>());
        var innerData = result.Where(x => x.Type == JTokenType.Array).Select(x => x.ToObject<List<InnerData>>());
```

there are classes:

```
 public class Token
        {
             public string token { set; get; }
        }
    public class InnerData
        {
            public string ts { set; get; }
            public string id { set; get; }
            public string val { set; get; }    
        }
```

You could print results as was mention before :

```
foreach (var token in tokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ts: " + token.token);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm afraid I am not able to use the resulting vars. Queries are new to me and I don't know, how to print the data contained in tokens and innerData. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: you could print linq results as was mentioned before. I added it to post answer